# Divinity 2 (Developer's Cut): How do I use herbalism and alchemy? Where do I find it?

Tags: divinity-2-ego-draconis

I assume I can use herbalism and alchemy in my "options" menu but I can't find it. I thought if I have chosen my 4 followers, there will be an icon in "options" to show that I can now use herbalism and alchemy.